# Determine quotes (and types of them) in bat variables

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Due to using some bash.exe calls from bat/cmd file I need to have some of my variables single-quoted, some of them - double quoted. And I'm converting some from one format to another. Is it possible to make it more universal: determine type of quotes and make them double-quoted for those who need it, otherwise make them single-quoted?

So we can have 3 types of input arguments:

```
set SOURCE="C:\SRC"
set SOURCE='C:\SRC'
set SOURCE=C:\SRC
```

And I'm need to determine types of input and convert it in these two forms:

```
SOURCE="C:\SRC"
SOURCE='C:\SRC'


rem -----------------------------------------------
rem      Converting SOURCE in
rem  single quoted format, very important to pass
rem  parameters to bash.exe!
rem -----------------------------------------------
set "SOURCE_CYG=%SOURCE:"='%"
```

Comment: It's hard to answer, as you don't show any relevant code

Comment: What about a single quoted variable with double quotes inside? and viceversa. And, escaped single\double quotes? And single quoted strings inside backquoted strings in singlequoted strings? Hope to be wrong, but seems that "universal" has a lot of cases. As jeb says, more coded needed.

Comment: Updated information/code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The small `:unquote` Batch subroutine, at end of code below, remove any quote from variable, so you may manage it in any way you wish:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set SOURCE="C:\SRC"
echo Original: %SOURCE%
call :unquote SOURCE
echo Double quotes: "%SOURCE%", single quotes: '%SOURCE%'
echo/

set SOURCE='C:\SRC'
echo Original: %SOURCE%
call :unquote SOURCE
echo Double quotes: "%SOURCE%", single quotes: '%SOURCE%'
echo/

set SOURCE=C:\SRC
echo Original: %SOURCE%
call :unquote SOURCE
echo Double quotes: "%SOURCE%", single quotes: '%SOURCE%'
echo/

goto :EOF

:unquote var
set quote="
if "!%1:~0,1!" equ "!quote!" set %1=!%1:~1,-1!
if "!%1:~0,1!" equ "'" set %1=!%1:~1,-1!
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the problem is what your sample code shows, then this is simple. Don't use quotes inside your variables. Assume no variable will have quotes in it and place the needed quotes in the correct places in code.

From batch code:

```
set "testVariable=this is a test"
bash test.sh
```

In test.sh

```
echo $testVariable
echo "$testVariable"
echo '$testVariable'
echo ----------------------
for a in $testVariable
do
    echo $a
done
echo ----------------------
for a in "$testVariable"
do
    echo $a
done
echo ----------------------
echo "'"$testVariable"'"
testVariable="'"$testVariable"'"
echo $testVariable
exit
```

This outputs

```
this is a test
this is a test
$testVariable
----------------------
this
is
a
test
----------------------
this is a test
----------------------
'this is a test'
'this is a test'
```

Comment: I'm asking about windows batch file, not sh one.

Comment: @AntonKochkov: Yes, the point is not using quotes inside variables, place them in the code where needed. The included sample is only a demostration that values are correctly passed/interpreted.

Comment: They are environment variables, so I'm need to deal with them as is.

Comment: Each time a process is created, a copy of the environment of the father process is generated, and set as the environment of the child. There is no "as is", change what you need. Code as if the varibles will never have quotes surronding value, including them in code where needed. If you control variable definition, ther will be no problem, and if you can't control how the variables get defined THEN the code from @Aacini answer will handle the required conversion.